# Failed to instantiate module Firebase due to Module 'Firebase' is not available

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm getting the following error trying to load the Firebase module in my angular.module function
[image]

Here is my web page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="" >
  <head>





    <!-- AngularJS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.0.3/firebase.js"></script>

    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.0.1/angularfire.min.js">   </script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/vendor/modernizr.js -->
    <script src="/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
    </head>
    <body ng-app="assetMgr">


    <!-- build:js scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
     <!--<script src="scripts/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/api.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/assets.js"></script> --->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is angular.module code:

```
 'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('assetMgr', ['Firebase']);
```

I'm lost as to why I'm getting this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The error below "Can not read src of null" is from which tag? Can you check  Firebase loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular module are case sensitive, change `Firebase` to `firebase` and you should be all set

```
'use strict';
 var app = angular.module('assetMgr', ['firebase']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing everthing correct Its just the name of firebase. You will need to change it to `firebase` instead of `Firebase`.